# Indexing matrices more efficiently (avoiding tf.gather)?

Tags: tensorflow

Given two matrices A and B (of dimensions N x K) and a list of indices iA = (a1, a2 ... aM) for A and iB = (b1, b2 ... bM) for B, I need to do the following:

```
lp = 0
for a in iA:
    for b in iB:
        lp += np.sum(A[a,] * B[b,])
```

in Tensorflow. The list of indices have repetitions, so we draw the same row more than once.

My current implementation looks like this:

```
lp = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(tf.gather(A, iA), tf.gather(B, iB)), 1)
```

However, the gradients are quite slow to compute (presumably because I'm using tf.gather). One can assume that iA is sorted in ascending order (so a particular row A[a,] can be reused until 'a' changes).
Is there a better way to do this? Any help is appreciated.

Edit: A and B are tf.Variables here and change for every iteration. Precomputing isn't an option. iA and iB however are constants and do not change.

Edit: M >> N. Size of K isn't really an issue.

Comment: As a comment to my answer. Can you tell us something about what sizes you have? I.e. how large is N, K, M?

Comment: M >> N . The size of K isn't really an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how dense your indices are, it may be a good idea to simply pre-compute an array of counts. In numpy that would be

```
counts = np.zeros_like(A)
np.add.at(counts, iA, 1)
np.add.at(counts, iB, 1)
```

You could then compute the indexed sum by simply multiplying by this and summing:

```
lp = np.sum(counts * A * B)
```

However, if `iA` and `iB` are both very sparse, this will give quite some performance overhead. The same applies if `iA` or `iB` are not fixed, but changes for each iteration.

Comment: My solution still works fine as long as `counts` can be precomputed. Is that an option?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply, but I guess the question was a bit ambiguous. A and B are Tensorflow's tf.Variables, and are updated during each pass, so the lp can't be precomputed. iA and IB are indices, so I suppose the second part of the answer might not really help.
Precomputing counts isn't really an option.

Thanks for your time! Much appreciated.

Comment: Also, iA and iB are not sparse. However, they are fixed and don't change during each iteration. :)